# Cannot add 2 blocks with phtml to one layout.xml file

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I have a page served up by the controller `landing_index_index` that brings in a couple of blocks to serve phtml. Now, when I bring in *just* one block:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Landing" name="landing" template="landing_page.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Everything is just fine. But when I bring in multiple, like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Landing" name="landing" template="landing_page.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="root">
        <block after="content" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Footer" name="landing" template="usfrienbr_footer.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

The first block no longer displays at all. If I do footer first and then the main page, only the main page will show. What am I doing that is causing this overwrite? Is it the name? If I change that I get a crash, because I think the name is supposed to correspond to the routes right?

Comment: give an unique name to block "name="landing"" both has same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your two custom block have the same name `name="landing"`, please change the name like below

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Landing" name="landing_page" template="landing_page.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="root">
    <block after="content" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Footer" name="usfrienbr_footer" template="usfrienbr_footer.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```