# Magento 2 Can i call two phtml file into one?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, custom, phtml

I have two phtml files, I want to use one for just the heading title and content.
then the second phtml file I want to use it to call a table with a simple form submission.
is this possible, if anyone could show me any example or guide will be helpful.

I have tried to use this but the content shows correctly but the root is showing after my footer
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206329/96152

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Header" name="header.content" template="header_page.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="root">
      <block before="footer-container" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Footer" name="custom_footer" template="custom_footer.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

Comment: when i put this the root is showing after my footer, i have used this code which i did mention on my question

Answer (score 0):

You can add a block to a phtml file and assign a specific template. E.g.

```
<?= $block->getLayout->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Custom_Module::form.phtml') ?>
```

In this example, a generic block class is specified for `createBlock`. This block class can render a phtml file that doesn't have any specific required arguments.

I am also referencing a template file from a hypothetical custom extension. It could point any existing module/template path.

Comment: i am trying to split a phtml in to two, i don't know how this will work please can you tell me how this work